# One-word synonym for "key activities"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm developing an information architecture for a web site, and one of the main tabs represents an area of the site that presents "Key Activities". The client is not excited about this label, and would prefer a one-word replacement (understandable for a main tab on a web site).

But we need a label that clearly, quickly, and intuitively communicates that the area contains:

- Activities this (government) organisation engages in that outline *how* it is tackling prioritized issues (which are identified in another area of the site)
- not *everything* the organization does, but most of the important activities; that is, we don't want to confuse the audience into expecting a comprehensive list.

Comment: This is too localized.

Comment: @Mitch: that sounds like a forum rule or guideline -- are those accessible somewhere that I may play by them?

Comment: Check both [What questions can I ask?](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) and [Why are some questions closed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close) from English.SE's [faq](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @Faust: to give the specifics (the general idea is in jimreed's links), your question isn't about a  synonym for jey activities, it is about your very localized circumstances and very localized desires for the word (your two bullet points) for your UI/product, unlikely to ever be desired by anybody else. If you had rewritten to be about the word and then commented about you motivation, that might be not so local.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if *priorities* might not be what you're looking for. Otherwise it might be difficult to find a single word that meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *priorities*, you might consider ***concerns***, ***issues***, ***involvement***, ***engagement***, or ***commitments***.

Answer (score 1):

Key activities might also be called **focuses**.

Answer (score 0):

What does the client call the key activities?

Does **Tasks** or **Tasking** make sense?

Comment: Not quite. More of a synonym for just "activities." Doesn't get at the "key" part. Nice try though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should clarify in the question whether you need a short word or phrase to fit into a constrained space as a column label, vs. a perhaps longer word or phrase for use as a window or tab label.  In following I assume you've room for several words, and present some suggested (or not :) phrases without further comment.

- Top Jobs Underway
- Top Jobs In Progress
- Work In Progress
- Main Works
- Main Means to Ends
- Means to Goals
- Now Engaged In
- Now Doing
- Now Advancing
- Current Works
- Work Highlights
- Key Paths to Goals
- Goal Achievement Methods
- Aweigh
- Golden Goals